# why in android studio 3.6.2 RecycelerView Does not work?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-xml

I updated Android Studio to version 3.6.2 and after adding the RecycelerView, I realized that it is not displayed in the design tab!

[image]

Comment: hi , if answer of your question working for you , you should mark that answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various reasons for Design tab fail to render layouts.

- Try changing the API levels in the design views.
- Clean build your project by going to Build > Clean build
- Ensure you don’t have any file from SDK that is missing
- Still if android studio is not able to render your layout then try by going File > Invalidate Cache/Restart